# Cocos2d iPhone v3.0 - Swiping up to perform an action

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, swipe-gesture

I am having some problems with setting up touches to swipe up to perform an actions.  I am trying to use the code below, but it will not recognize the touches.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

//Swipe Detection Part 1
firstTouch = location;

    CCLOG(@"touched");
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


//Swipe Detection Part 2
lastTouch = location;

//Minimum length of the swipe
float swipeLength = ccpDistance(firstTouch, lastTouch);


CCActionJumpTo *jump1 = [CCActionJumpTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(self.contentSize.width*.4,self.contentSize.height*.1) height:self.contentSize.height*.5 jumps:1];
[_fufunaken runAction:[CCActionRepeat actionWithAction:jump1 times:1]];


//Check if the swipe is an up swipe and long enough
if (firstTouch.y > lastTouch.y && swipeLength > 60) {
    [_fufunaken runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:jump1]];
}

}
```

It isn't even saying "touched" when I touch the screen and I do have user interactions enabled in init.  Any help will be apprectiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cocos2d v3 you need to replace all `ccTouchesBegan/ccTouchesMoved/ccTouchesEnded` to

```
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The good news is that you can get the current location of the touch by simply using the following line

```
CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

all of this is therefore, not required

```
/*
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
*/
```